# GIT Is there an easy way to indicate who write class/method in file

Tags: git, github

Is there an easy way to indicate who write class/method if there is multiple classes or methods in file and file was edited by multiple developers during it's life?

Comment: [`git blame`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html).

Comment: "who write..." is too broad definition. Who write initial version? Who is author of last edit? Who has the most amount of edits during life-time?

Answer (score 1):

As @Lazy_Badger said, this question is a little vague. (For example, if the class was refactored out of a larger class, are you looking for the author of the larger class, or the author of the refactor?) Still, here are a couple tools that I like, when regular `git blame` isn't quite good enough:

- Look in the `git log`. If you have good commit messages, the commit that creates a class should definitely have that class name somewhere in the commit message. If not, you can use the `-S` flag to search for commits containing certain strings in the code.
- Use the [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin for vim. That plugin gives you a `GBlame` command that's very similar to `git blame`, but it can do some neat tricks. For example, if you press `P` with your cursor over a blame line, Fugitive will re-blame that file at the parent of the commit you were over. Basically: "Show me what the blame looked like before this change." You can find the original commit quickly by doing that over and over.